# Detect "overall average" color of the picture

Tags: php, javascript, python, image-processing

I have a jpg image.

I need to know "overall average" the color of the image. At first glance there can use the histogram of the image (channel RGB).

At work I use mostly JavaScript and PHP (a little Python) therefore welcomed the decision in these languages. Maybe ther are library for working with images that address similar problems.

I do not need to dynamically determine the color of the picture. I need just once go through the entire array of images and determine the color of each separately (this information I will remember for future use).

Comment: JS cannot access the colour information of a binary image

Comment: @mplungjan, there is such a javascript library `http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/`, they somehow get information about colors. or am I mistaken?

Comment: They use the new `Canvas` element.

Comment: it looks like the library you posted is only supported by HTML 5.... and it says only firefox can support all features.

Comment: "getImageData() / putImageData() methods available on the HTML5 canvas element."

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use **PHP** to get an array of the color palette like so:

```
<?php 
function colorPalette($imageFile, $numColors, $granularity = 5) 
{ 
   $granularity = max(1, abs((int)$granularity)); 
   $colors = array(); 
   $size = @getimagesize($imageFile); 
   if($size === false) 
   { 
      user_error("Unable to get image size data"); 
      return false; 
   } 
   $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
   // Andres mentioned in the comments the above line only loads jpegs, 
   // and suggests that to load any file type you can use this:
   // $img = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imageFile)); 

   if(!$img) 
   { 
      user_error("Unable to open image file"); 
      return false; 
   } 
   for($x = 0; $x < $size[0]; $x += $granularity) 
   { 
      for($y = 0; $y < $size[1]; $y += $granularity) 
      { 
         $thisColor = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y); 
         $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($img, $thisColor); 
         $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
         $thisRGB = sprintf('%02X%02X%02X', $red, $green, $blue); 
         if(array_key_exists($thisRGB, $colors)) 
         { 
            $colors[$thisRGB]++; 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $colors[$thisRGB] = 1; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
   arsort($colors); 
   return array_slice(array_keys($colors), 0, $numColors); 
} 
// sample usage: 
$palette = colorPalette('rmnp8.jpg', 10, 4); 
echo "<table>\n"; 
foreach($palette as $color) 
{ 
   echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#$color;width:2em;'>&nbsp;</td><td>#$color</td></tr>\n"; 
} 
echo "</table>\n";
```

Which gives you an array whose values are higher for how often that color has been used.

**EDIT**
A commenter asked how to use this on all files in a directory, here it is:

```
    if ($handle = opendir('./path/to/images')) {

        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
           $palette = colorPalette($file, 10, 4);
           echo "<table>\n"; 
           foreach($palette as $color) { 
               echo "<tr><td style='background-color:#$color;width:2em;'>&nbsp;</td><td>#$color</td></tr>\n"; 
           } 
           echo "</table>\n";
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
```

might not want to do this on too many files, but it's your server.

Alternatively if you'd rather use **Javascript** [Lokesh's Color-Theif](https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief) library does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Make it Bang! Change `$img = @imagecreatefromgif($imageFile);` to `$img = @imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imageFile));` and you can now process different image types...

Comment: the code to change is actually `@imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);` it currently assumes you're using jpgs.

Comment: Oops! Thanks @JKirchartz for catching my craziness. Great code by the way!

Comment: How would you change this, to do the action for all pictures in a directory?

Comment: @Sycren updated my answer, with the help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539978/read-images-from-a-directory-using-php

Comment: how can I do to separate each color and add in a linear gradient, example: linear-gradient (90deg, #$color1 40%, #$color2 100%)

Comment: whats the $granularity stand for?

Comment: @ArmanGin `$granularity` determines how often the colors are sampled from the image, it's used in the `for` loop to increment the x/y position to determine which pixels to sample.

Answer (score 7):

Combining JKirchartz and Alexander Hugestrand answer:

```
 function getAverage($sourceURL){

    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourceURL);
    $scaled = imagescale($image, 1, 1, IMG_BICUBIC); 
    $index = imagecolorat($scaled, 0, 0);
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($scaled, $index); 
    $red = round(round(($rgb['red'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    $green = round(round(($rgb['green'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    $blue = round(round(($rgb['blue'] / 0x33)) * 0x33); 
    return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $red, $green, $blue); 
 }
```

Tried and tested, returns hex string.

Comment: Why round it? In my experience, not rounding it provides a more precise result, just ```return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', $rgb['red'], $rgb['green'], $rgb['blue']);```

Comment: @Kevin will have to try it out - thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Does it fail at particular colours?

Comment: Shouldn't line #3 reference $scaled instead of $image?  This appears to create the scaled image, but never use it - and instead base the results on the pixel at 0,0 of the original image.  You may want to update your answer if my reading is correct.

Comment: returns `#000000` for me on all images.

Comment: @ashleedawg For some reason the `imagescale` function only works properly when using the `IMG_NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR` or `IMG_BILINEAR_FIXED` resizing algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

```
$img = glob('img/*');
foreach ($img as $key => $value) {
    $info = getimagesize($value);
    $mime = $info['mime'];
    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
            break;
        case 'image/png':
            $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
            break;
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
            break;
    }
    $avg = $image_create_func($value);
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($value);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(1, 1);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $avg, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, $width, $height);
    $rgb = imagecolorat($tmp, 0, 0);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
    echo '<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align: top; display:inline-block; width:100px; height:150px; margin:5px; padding:5px; background-color:rgb('.$r.','.$g.','.$b.');">';
    echo '<img style="width:auto; max-height:100%; max-width: 100%; vertical-align:middle; height:auto; margin-bottom:5px;" src="'.$value.'">';
    echo '</div>';
```

you can get the value of the average color with $r, $g, & $b
resample the image is much more better than only scale it !

Comment: the first working answer I found for this task, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A shorter solution for true color image would be to scale it down to 1x1 pixel size and sample the color at that pixel:

$scaled = imagescale($img, 1, 1, IMG_BICUBIC);
$meanColor = imagecolorat($img, 0, 0);

...but I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: interesting, but need to to be tested.

Comment: note, this requires PHP to be compiled with the GD library

Comment: I guess this creates average, not main color.

Comment: This solution works great, but not with `IMG_BICUBIC` as the interpolation mode. I found that the color it produces as far away from the average color calculated by Gimp. Some modes are quite horrible, but many of them produce similar results. I settled for `IMG_GAUSSIAN`.

Answer (score 2):

I've created the composer package that provides the library for picking an average color from the given image by its path.

You can install it by running the following command within your project directory:

```
composer require tooleks/php-avg-color-picker
```

Usage example:

```
<?php

use Tooleks\Php\AvgColorPicker\Gd\AvgColorPicker;

$imageAvgHexColor = (new AvgColorPicker)->getImageAvgHexByPath('/absolute/path/to/the/image.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)');

// The `$imageAvgHexColor` variable contains the average color of the given image in HEX format (#fffff).
```

See the [documentation](https://packagist.org/packages/tooleks/php-avg-color-picker).

Answer (score 1):

Start with PIL.  http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Open the Image object.  Use the `getdata` method to get all pixels.  Average the values you get back.

Something like this.

[Image color detection using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270874/image-color-detection-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using [php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips). It's very fast, and will find the most *common* colour, rather than the average colour.

Most photos will have grey as the average, since that's what auto white balance does. What you really want is the colour which appears most often.

This program uses a 3D histogram. It makes a 10 x 10 x 10 cube (you can change this, see `$n_bins`) to represent the whole of RGB colourspace, then loops through the image counting the number of pixels which fall into each bin. It sets the count in bin (0, 0, 0) to zero (black is usually uninteresting background), then searches for the bin with the highest count. The index of that bin is the most common RGB colour.

This won't work for most PNGs (you'll need to flatten out the alpha) or CMYKs (you'll need to convert to RGB first).

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Jcupitt\Vips;

$im = Vips\Image::newFromFile($argv[1], ['access' => 'sequential']);

# 3D histogram ... make 10 x 10 x 10 bins, so 1000 possible colours
$n_bins = 10;
$hist = $im->hist_find_ndim(['bins' => $n_bins]);

# black is usually background or boring, so set that cell to 0 counts
# fetch (0, 0, set the 0th element of that to 0, paste back
$pixel = $hist->getpoint(0, 0);
$pixel[0] = 0;
$pixel = Vips\Image::black(1, 1)->add($pixel);
$hist = $hist->insert($pixel, 0, 0);

# (x, y) pixel with the most counts
[$v, $x, $y] = $hist->maxpos();
$pixel = $hist->getpoint($x, $y);
$z = array_search($v, $pixel);

# convert indexes to rgb ... +0.5 to get the centre of each bin
$r = ($x + 0.5) * 256 / $n_bins;
$g = ($y + 0.5) * 256 / $n_bins;
$b = ($z + 0.5) * 256 / $n_bins;

echo("r = " . $r . "\n");
echo("g = " . $g . "\n");
echo("b = " . $b . "\n");
```

I can run it like this:

```
$ time ./try302.php ~/pics/shark.jpg 
r = 38.4
g = 38.4
b = 12.8
real    0m0.077s
user    0m0.068s
sys 0m0.016s
```

So 70ms on this modest laptop for a 700 x 700 pixel jpg.