# dechex not showing first two zeros (rgb to hex php)

Tags: php, colors, hex, rgb

I use this php script to get the rgb color from a jpg file:

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321726/8144877

the problem is when the rgb color look like this: rgb(0, 23, 110) then the script returns this hex: 176e and not 00176e

I see that the script not showing the first two zeros, is there a way to showing all the zeros when using dechex to convert rgb to hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's a way, [`str_pad` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) is there to help you:

```
str_pad("176e", 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // "00176e"
```

Arguments:

1. input string
2. expected length
3. padding character
4. padding mode - in your case `STR_PAD_LEFT` is needed to pad on the left side

Comment: I used like this and now its working correctly  `<?php $image=imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');$thumb=imagecreatetruecolor(1,1); imagecopyresampled($thumb,$image,0,0,0,0,1,1,imagesx($image),imagesy($image));$mainColor=str_pad((dechex(imagecolorat($thumb,0,0))), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);echo $mainColor; ?>`