# How can I turn a hex code into a colour word (like blue, green, red,..)

Tags: php, database, image, image-processing, colors

So I have used this simple PHP script to get **one main colour** out of an image.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36321726/7278089

[image]
*The highlighted number is the hex but without a # in front.*

I want our platform to be able to filter on colors but when a user is creating a post it will search for the one main colour in his image and then save it into the DB. But here is the thing that I'm searching for **I don't want to save away for example #0d66ac which is blue.** **I just want it to insert into the table as `color=blue;`**

Answer (score 1):

Use this script to match a color (HEX) with the color "name", you could simply pass the result to PHP.

Subsequently, when a match has been found, pass it off to your table.

http://chir.ag/projects/ntc/ntc.js

Comment: Ye but I want it much smaller like a pool of 11 names or something.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to convert hex to rgb you can use sscanf:

```
<?php
     $hex = "#ff9900";
     list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($hex, "#%02x%02x%02x");
     echo "$hex -> $r $g $b";
?>
```