# How can I insert data from a picture into an 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I am making an AI that can play the game connect 4, from a picture of one state of the game e.g : [click to see](https://www.google.com/search?q=connect%204&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6mdzoqdfqAhXUasAKHaWTC1kQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=1021&bih=684#imgrc=JFoA4eSacyuyCM&imgdii=q-k1YtqBGHZdfM)

This script below, is detecting red elements from a picture:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
 
img = cv2.imread('connect.png')
 
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 
#get red color 
lower_range = np.array([169, 100, 100])
upper_range = np.array([189, 255, 255])
 
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_range, upper_range)
 
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

I would like to insert these data into a 2D array to be able to use this array as a game state and determine which move the AI should make.

I have tried to find a solution on Stack Overflow and on Internet but overall I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: have you looked at this example https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html

Comment: @jayprich thank you for your answer this is useful to find all tokens by color because in my case I can save coin.png and use it like in the example !

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to read a picture and to cast it in **a 2-dimensional numpy array** with `np.array(in_image)`:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
from skimage import io, transform


path = "C:/my/path/"
pic = 'myPic.png'
imgName = path+pic

in_image_0 = skimage.io.imread(imgName)                   # read the image
in_image_1 = skimage.color.rgb2gray(in_image_0)           # transform it to grey-scale
in_image_2 = skimage.transform.rescale(in_image_1, 0.5)   # change the resolution
in_image_3 = np.flipud(np.array(in_image_2))              # make a numpy array and flip it up/down
```

Comment: I would just add that you need to open your file like this       path =r "C:/my/path/""

Comment: But how can I determine what is the color value and the positionning of it in the image with this method

Comment: There are many different ways to do that. Search for `skimage  color detecting` e.g.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=skimage++color+detecting&client=firefox-b-d&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjrjY6HhtrqAhWuVBUIHVy2BrcQsAR6BAgKEAE&biw=1920&bih=938#imgrc=F9GGBdLsxeWH3M

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270874/image-color-detection-using-python